# Is there any way to use Automator or a script to change all the font colors on each slide in a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: ms-office, automator, font, color

The professor did not use a template and each text box was made as he created the presentation. Text color varies through the various sentences highlighting words, but I would like to remove these.

I tried messing with the master slide, but that did not help. Any help here would really be awesome, because I'm going to have this professor for at least two more classes, and each presentation is well over 140 slides.